# How to integrate iiif image viewer in Php project?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, iiif

I want to use iiif http://iiif.io/ in my Codeigniter project but I haven't found any helpful link or demo which can help me to use this framework.

I'm also planning to use http://www.iiifhosting.com/ for hosting images and its demo shows they provide an image viewer too, but can I customise this viewer just like IIPMooViewer, Mirador, OpenSeadragon or any other viewer listed in iiif.io viewer list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://iiif.io/api/image/2.1/):

> The IIIF [International Image Interoperability Framework] Image API specifies a **web service** that returns an image in response to a standard HTTP or HTTPS request. **The URI can specify the region, size, rotation, quality characteristics and format of the requested image.**

For the server, you can deploy your own server such as [Loris](https://github.com/pulibrary/loris) or [IIPImage server](http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/server/). You can also use an hosting service such as http://www.iiifhosting.com/ .

For the client, you can integrate a client such as [Mirador](http://projectmirador.org/), [OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/) into your website but you can also directly use the IIIF protocol, using the [URI syntax](http://iiif.io/api/image/2.1/#uri-syntax):

```
{scheme}://{server}{/prefix}/{identifier}/{region}/{size}/{rotation}/{quality}.{format}
```

Comment: yes I've used iiifhosting and OpenSeaDragon into website, hope it will help someone else here. Thanks!